How to control the value of a field in an sql query with the Business Text plugin Grafana?
I use the Business Text plugin and I would like to display a different image depending on the value returned by my sql query.
Example:
SELECT Field1 FROM Table1 WHERE id=1
Result:
Field1 = 3

Image to display depending on the value of Field1:
IF Field1 = 1 THEN
src = “path1/path2/img1”
ELSE
IF Field1 = 2 THEN
src=…
ELSE

# …

I don't know which function to use to retrieve the value of the field from my sql query
